# Redis giving the error: TypeError: Connection.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I am integrating the celery in our project. Redis giving the error when, I am trying to run this command

`python -m celery -A claims_dashboard worker`

```
# Celery settings.py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://0.0.0.0:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://0.0.0.0:6379"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

```
# celery.py
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "claims_dashboard.settings")
app = Celery("claims_dashboard")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

```
#init.py file
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

This is the traceback of my code , I have not write anywhere the "username" in my code.

```
(django-venv) naveenprakashsatyarthi@LAP-ART-MP283WK5:~/Desktop/Artivatic/claims_dashboard/claims_dashboard_backend/claims_dashboard$ python -m celery -A claims_dashboard worker
 
 -------------- celery@LAP-ART-MP283WK5 v5.1.1 (sun-harmonics)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-53-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2022-11-23 05:25:07
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         claims_dashboard:0x7f233d74ba90
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://0.0.0.0:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://0.0.0.0:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[2022-11-23 05:25:07,912: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError("Connection.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 925, in create_channel
    return self._avail_channels.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1067, in get_connection
    connection = self._available_connections.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 326, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/connection.py", line 21, in start
    c.connection = c.connect()
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 422, in connect
    conn = self.connection_for_read(heartbeat=self.amqheartbeat)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 428, in connection_for_read
    return self.ensure_connected(
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 454, in ensure_connected
    conn = conn.ensure_connection(
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 381, in ensure_connection
    self._ensure_connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 312, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 877, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 812, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 949, in establish_connection
    self._avail_channels.append(self.create_channel(self))
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 927, in create_channel
    channel = self.Channel(connection)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 737, in __init__
    self.client.ping()
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1106, in ping
    return self.execute_command('PING')
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 836, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1069, in get_connection
    connection = self.make_connection()
  File "/home/naveenprakashsatyarthi/django-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1107, in make_connection
    return self.connection_class(**self.connection_kwargs)
TypeError: Connection.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

Comment: What is the pip package versions of `django`, `celery` and `redis` ?

Comment: @JPG django version : 4.1.1, celery version : 5.1.1,

Comment: @JPG Redis version: Redis server v=6.0.16 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.2.1 bits=64 build=a3fdef44459b3ad6

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @naveenSatyarthi did you get past this?